# .NET equivalent of Delphi's forceDirectory

Tags: c#, .net, delphi

Does anyone know what's the .NET/C# equivalent of Delphi's forceDirectory function ? For who   don't know delphi, forceDirectory creates all the directories in a given path if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The method [`Directory.CreateDirectory(path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx) automatically creates all the directories/subdirectories specified in the path. From the [**Remarks**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx):

> Any and all directories specified in *path* are created

Comment: You believe correctly, from the Remarks: "Any and all directories specified in path are created". The restrictions nd conditions are the same as for ForceDirectory

Comment: just FYI for people who come across this - you can't use this to create the directories from filename path. It will create folders from the file name as well